# Dynamically construct querystring behaviour in IE and FF / Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code

```
function LoadContent(Id) {
        alert('Controls/Network/NetworkDetail.aspx?' + rnd() + '&CtlId=' + Id);
        $.get('Controls/Network/NetworkDetail.aspx?' + rnd() + '&CtlId=' + Id, function(data) {
            $(Id).append(data);
        });
        $(Id).removeClass("Waiting");
}
```

works perfectly in IE7. the alert displayed intended querystring, and NetworkDetail.aspx page can obtain the CtlId using Request.QueryString["CtlId"]

However, using FF3 and Chrome, Request.QueryString["CtlId"] returns null but the alert displayed the querystring correctly (no difference to IE7).

the Id value is usually '#Tab1', or "#Tab2"

Any idea on how to correctly construct querystring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The # indicates a named anchor in HTML and therefore is not part of the querystring, perhaps you sould correctly URL encode your id's.

e.g. #Tab1 becomes %35Tab1

Try using escape. e.g.

'Controls/Network/NetworkDetail.aspx?' + rnd() + '&CtlId=' + escape(Id)

Comment: You're right. '#' messes my code. But still, browser quirks like this is exactly why I hate javascript development.

Comment: IE should not have sent the # part of the URL, as this is intended for the browser not the server, but i do see their point. BTW, using escape also gets over any issues if other URL characters appear in the ID (such as & or ?).